# sifr Problem - everything invisible

Tags: sifr, invisible

As far as I use `sifr.setup();` every h2, h1, and so on becomes invisible. But I don't want that.

I just want the "selectors" to provide a replacement and become invisible and replaced.

How can I prevent that?

I also have another problem where every font is blue and it never gets that color from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've kept the original CSS, which hides those elements. Have a look at the CSS file and remove the original `.sIFR-hasFlash h1` selectors.

Can you post an example for the color problem?